# How to get shared CSS body class between translated WPML pages

Tags: php, css, plugin-wpml

I need to add the same CSS class to `<body>` element of all translatons of a page, but the CSS class added with `body_class()` is different for each translation because it is taken from the translated title of the page.

For example, for *about us* page I get this markup:

```
<body class="about-us">        // English
<body class="sobre-nosotros">  // Spanish
```

I want to get the same class for both languages:

```
<body class="about-us">        // English
<body class="about-us">        // Spanish
```

Is there a way to add the same CSS class for all translations of the same page?

Thank you.

Comment: It’s probably not a good practice to base your styling on the names of content to begin with. I suggest using a template-level class or similar for styling.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. The page has a custom template shared with other pages with another design. I would try to avoid this approach.

Comment: Different designs should have different templates, no? Or some sort of specific class or markup to distinguish them. Styling based on specific content leads to exactly this sort of issue. If you follow my advice you will avoid problems like this in future. "About us" is never going to be an accurate way to define a design element anyway. Descriptors like "blue", "wide", "inverted" or even just "alternate" would describe design differences *and* be reusable.

Comment: I understand. In this case, the same template is used by two different pages with different styles but the same HTML markup. So, I can duplicate the template to do what you are saying. but this templates, since it should generate the same markup, must be identical. Is a good practice to make two identical templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use post name to style your page. Maybe you can use template page.

But if you still want to do it, you can do something like this:

```
function add_default_language_slug_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $default_language = wpml_get_default_language(); // will return languague code of your default language for example 'en'
        // get the post ID in default language
        $default_post_id = icl_object_id($post->ID, 'post', FALSE,$default_language);
        // get the post object
        $default_post_obj = get_post($default_post_id);
        // get the name
        $default_post_name = $default_post_obj->post_name;
        // add default language post name to body class
        $classes[] = $default_post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_default_language_slug_class' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by `body_class` filter. You can add class to body like this-

```
// Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter( 'body_class', 'the_dramatist_body_classes' );
function the_dramatist_body_classes( $classes ) {
    return $classes[] = 'body-of-' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
}
```

And then you can write CSS like below-

```
body[class^="body-of-"] {
    color: red;
}
```

So what is actually happening above ? First we are adding *body-of-en* for **English** and *body-of-es* for **Spanish** site and then we are adding CSS style by selecting them with `body[class^="body-of-"]` means by the first part of the class we added to the body. This way we can easily add separate class to different language site's body as well as use them for applying same style also.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Looks good. I'll try it asap to mark your answer as solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it is not correct because it add same class to all pages and diferent to each language. I'm asking for adding a different class for each page slug.

Comment: Uh I see.... So as you already accepted previous answer I'm not researching on this anymore. :)